VBA code has Run Time 1004 Error midway through copying data
I am trying to take data from a table and copy it over to another sheet based on an employee's position and contract #. The issue is that on some of the contract #s (but not all) the code will stop executing midway through the table and give a

Run-time error 1004
Application-defined or object-defined error.

The odd part is that up until this point the code is working perfectly. The code is throwing the error the when I try calling WhatPosition within the for loop in the Move function. I have also tried running the code without those two lines, only filling in columns a and b, and it works totally fine through the whole list.
Sub Hourly()
  Call Move("1")
 ' Call Move("2")
 ' Call Move("3")
 ' Call Move("4")
End Sub
Public Function LastRow(sheet, col) As Integer
    Dim wb2 As Excel.Workbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("wb2")
        With wb2.Worksheets(sheet)
            Dim lr As Integer:  lr = .Cells(.Rows.count, col).End(xlUp).Row
        End With
    LastRow = lr
End Function
Sub Move(contract)
    Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("wb1")
    Dim s1 As Excel.Worksheet
    Set s1 = wb1.Worksheets("sheet1")
    Dim wb2 As Excel.Workbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("wb2")
    
        Dim oList As ListObject
        Set oList = s1.ListObjects("table1")
        
        Dim oRow As ListRow
        Dim test As Long
        Dim count As Integer
        count = 1
        
        For Each oRow In oList.ListRows
            count = count + 1
            If s1.Cells(count, 5).Value = contract Then
                test = test + 1
                wb2.Worksheets(WhatTab(contract)).Cells(LastRow(WhatTab(contract), 1) + 1, 1).Value = s1.Cells(count, 1).Value
                wb2.Worksheets(WhatTab(contract)).Cells(LastRow(WhatTab(contract), 2) + 1, 2).Value = s1.Cells(count, 3).Value
             
                wb2.Worksheets(WhatTab(contract)).Cells(LastRow(WhatTab(contract), 1), WhatPosition(contract, count, s1)).Value = s1.Cells(count, 6).Value
                wb2.Worksheets(WhatTab(contract)).Cells(LastRow(WhatTab(contract), 1), WhatPosition(contract, count, s1) + 1).Value = s1.Cells(count, 7).Value
            End If
        Next oRow
End Sub

Public Function WhatTab(contract) As String
    If contract = "1" Then
        WhatTab = "1"
    Else
        If contract = "2" Then
        WhatTab = "2"
        Else
            If contract = "3" Then
            WhatTab = "3 e"
            Else
                If contract = "4" Then
                WhatTab = "4 e"
                Else: MsgBox "New Contract Number or Changed Sheet Name"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function
Public Function WhatPosition(contract, counter, sheet) As Integer
    Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("wb1")
    Dim s1 As Excel.Worksheet
    Set s1 = wb1.Worksheets("sheet1")
    Dim position As String
    position = s1.Cells(counter, 4).Value
    If contract = "3" Then
            If position = "a" Then
            WhatPosition = 3
            Else
                If position = "b" Then
                WhatPosition = 10
                Else
                    If position = "c" Then
                    WhatPosition = 17
                    Else
                        If position = "d" Then
                        WhatPosition = 24
                        Else
                            If position = "e" Then
                            WhatPosition = 31
                            Else
                                If position = "f" Then
                                WhatPosition = 38
                                Else
                                    If position = "g" Then
                                    WhatPosition = 45
                                    Else
                                        If position = "h" Then
                                        WhatPosition = 52
                                        Else
                                            If position = "i" Then
                                            WhatPosition = 59
                                            Else
                                                If position = "j" Then
                                                WhatPosition = 66
                                                End If
                                            End If
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
    Else
        If position = "a" Then
            WhatPosition = 3
            Else
                If position = "b" Then
                WhatPosition = 7
                Else
                    If position = "c" Then
                    WhatPosition = 11
                    Else
                        If position = "d" Then
                        WhatPosition = 15
                        Else
                            If position = "e" Then
                            WhatPosition = 19
                            Else
                                If position = "f" Then
                                WhatPosition = 23
                                Else
                                    If position = "g" Then
                                    WhatPosition = 27
                                    Else
                                        If position = "h" Then
                                        WhatPosition = 31
                                        Else
                                            If position = "i" Then
                                            WhatPosition = 35
                                            Else
                                                If position = "j" Then
                                                WhatPosition = 39
                                                End If
                                            End If
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
    End If
    
End Function

To reiterate, the code, including the code calling WhatPosition, works as intended and copies the data until midway through the list it's looping through (table1 which is on sheet1 in wb1). It is giving this issue consistently on contracts 1 and 2, 3 and 4 always work fine. It always stops at the exact same rows, count 24 for contract 1 and 22 for contract 2; there is nothing unusual about these rows in the table.

If you click "Debug" when the error pops up, which line is highlighted.  FYI I'd consider looking at Select Case to replace those longer If Else blocks.

Your functions LastRow and WhatTab both open files which were already opened by the calling code?

@Tim Williams the line highlighted is
wb2.Worksheets(WhatTab(contract)).Cells(LastRow(WhatTab(contract), 1), WhatPosition(contract, count, s1)).Value = s1.Cells(count, 6).Value
in the for loop of the move function. Agreed on the if else.
Not sure what you mean by opening files; the intention of those two functions is just to 1) determine the last row with that isnt blank in a given sheet and column within the workbook I am copying to and to 2) determine which tab to paste to based on the contract number. Where are they opening files?

Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("wb2") in LastRow for example

If you just need to reference an already-open workbook, then use (eg) Workbooks("wb.xlsx")

@Tim Williams Ok, is there a better way of setting the wb1 and wb2 variables to specific filepaths that doesn't also try to open them? I'm trying to research it but the answers I'm finding aren't working.

If you have a reference to a workbook or a worksheet in Move and you need to reference that same workbook or sheet in a method called from Move then that best approach is to pass the reference from Move directly to the called method, by adding it as a parameter on the called method.

@TimWilliams I modified the code so that the references are passed to WhatPosition and LastRow. The code is now running somewhat faster which is great, but unfortunately the code is still breaking midway through the list at the same line.

As Tim said - A bunch of suggestions below. Compiled but not tested:
Sub Hourly()
  Call Move("1")
 ' Call Move("2")
 ' Call Move("3")
 ' Call Move("4")
End Sub

Sub Move(Contract As String)
    Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("wb1")
    Dim s1 As Excel.Worksheet
    Set s1 = wb1.Worksheets("sheet1")
    Dim wb2 As Excel.Workbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("wb2")
    
    Dim oList As ListObject
    Set oList = s1.ListObjects("table1")
        
    Dim oRow As ListRow
    Dim r As Long, PositionColumn As Long, NewRow As Long
    Dim WhatWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim Position As String
    Dim Source As Range
    For r = 1 To oList.ListRows.Count
        Set Source = oList.ListRows(r).Range
        If Source(1, 5).Value = Contract Then
            Set WhatWorksheet = GetWhatWorksheet(Contract, wb2)
            If Not WhatWorksheet Is Nothing Then
                
                Position = s1.Cells(r, 4).Value
                PositionColumn = WhatPositionColumn(Contract, Position)
                
                With WhatWorksheet
                    NewRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    
                    .Cells(NewRow, 1).Value = Source(1, 1).Value
                    .Cells(NewRow, 2).Value = Source(1, 3).Value
                    .Cells(NewRow, PositionColumn).Value = Source(1, 6).Value
                    .Cells(NewRow, PositionColumn + 1).Value = Source(1, 7).Value
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Public Function GetWhatWorksheet(Contract As String, wb As Workbook) As Worksheet
    Dim WorksheetName As String
    WorksheetName = WhatTab(Contract)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetWhatWorksheet = wb.Worksheets(WorksheetName)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Worksheet("; WorksheetName; ") for"; Contract; "not found"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Public Function WhatTab(Contract As String) As String
    Select Case Contract
        Case "1"
            WhatTab = "1"
        Case "2"
            WhatTab = "2"
        Case "3"
            WhatTab = "3 e"
        Case "4"
            WhatTab = "4 e"
        Case Else
            MsgBox "New Contract Number or Changed Sheet Name"
    End Select
End Function

Public Function WhatPositionColumn(Contract As String, Position As String) As Long
    If Contract = "3" Then
        WhatPositionColumn = Switch( _
            Position = "a", 3, _
            Position = "b", 10, _
            Position = "c", 17, _
            Position = "d", 24, _
            Position = "e", 31, _
            Position = "f", 38, _
            Position = "g", 45, _
            Position = "h", 52, _
            Position = "i", 59, _
            Position = "j", 66 _
        )
    Else
        WhatPositionColumn = Switch( _
            Position = "a", 3, _
            Position = "b", 7, _
            Position = "c", 11, _
            Position = "d", 15, _
            Position = "e", 19, _
            Position = "f", 23, _
            Position = "g", 27, _
            Position = "h", 31, _
            Position = "i", 35, _
            Position = "j", 39 _
        )
    End If
End Function

Note: Although, not an issue here. There is no advantage to using the Integer data-type which has a max value of 32,767, use Long instead which has a cap of 2,147,483,647.  This will prevent an overflow error when working with large datasets.
My aim was to demonstrate some techniques that will simplify and make the code easier to read and modify.

Thanks! I replaced with this code and it ran much smoother. Realized my initial error was caused by a dataset issue that I missed (errant spaces) but this made the code run much faster.

A bunch of suggestions below.
Compiled but not tested:
Sub Hourly()
    Move "1" 'use of `Call` is deprecated
    Move "2"
    Move "3"
    Move "4"
End Sub

Sub Move(contract As String)
    
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, s1 As Worksheet, wb2 As Excel.Workbook
    Dim oList As ListObject, rw As Range, colPos As Long, position As String
    Dim test As Long, theRow1 As Long, theRow2 As Long, wsDest As Worksheet

    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("wb1")
    Set s1 = wb1.Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set oList = s1.ListObjects("table1")
    
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("wb2")
    Set wsDest = wb2.Worksheets(WhatTab(contract)) 'destination worksheet
    
    For Each rw In oList.DataBodyRange.Rows   'for each row of data in `table1`
        If rw.Cells(5).Value = contract Then  'contract matches?
            theRow1 = LastRow(wsDest, 1)
            theRow2 = LastRow(wsDest, 2)
            position = rw.Cells(4).Value
            colPos = WhatColumn(contract, position)
            ' ? what to do if colPos is zero ?
            With wsDest
               .Cells(theRow1 + 1, 1).Value = rw.Cells(1).Value
               .Cells(theRow2 + 1, 2).Value = rw.Cells(3).Value
               .Cells(theRow1, colPos).Value = rw.Cells(6).Value
               .Cells(theRow1, colPos + 1).Value = rw.Cells(7).Value
            End With
        End If
    Next rw
End Sub

Public Function LastRow(ws As Worksheet, col) As Long 'prefer Long over Integer
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, col).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

Public Function WhatTab(contract As String) As String
    Select Case contract 'better with Select Case
        Case "1", "2": WhatTab = contract
        Case "3", "4": WhatTab = contract & " e"
        Case Else: MsgBox "New Contract Number or Changed Sheet Name"
    End Select
End Function

Public Function WhatColumn(contract As String, position As String) As Long
    Dim i As Long, incr As Long
    If position Like "[a-j]" Then          'position is in range a-j?
        i = asc(position) - 96             'a=1, b=2 etc
        incr = IIf(contract = "3", 7, 4)   'increment by 7 or by 4 ?
        WhatColumn = 3 + ((i - 1) * 7)     'calculate column position
    End If
End Function


Thanks, when I tried to deploy this WhatColumn was always returning as 0, but when I replaced that with TinMan's solution below it worked!

Here’s an alternative approach to simplify the UDF below.
Public Function WhatPositionColumn(Contract As String, Position As String) As Long
    Dim aCol
    If Contract = "3" Then
        aCol = Array(3,10,17,24,31,38,45,52,59,66)
    Else
        aCol = Array(3,7,11,15,19,23,27,31,35,39)
    End If
    If Position Like "[a-j]" Then
        WhatPositionColumn = aCol(Asc(Position)-Asc("a"))
    End If
End Function



If Like "[a-j]" Then ?

Thanks @SpectralInstance. It's a typo. I've fixed it.
